# SQL Server 2005 Default Backup Plan

Tags: sql-server, backup, maintenance

I noticed that a newly imported database on SQLServer 2005 had configured itself (without my knowledge) to perform daily backups; but it's not deleting old files and quickly filling up the disk.

I don't know how the backup job got configured (maybe that's something that gets transferred when you move a database?) but I'm having trouble modifying it.

The backup runs as part of SQL Server Agent job called "Daily Backups". This job runs a package called "(SSIS Packages)\Maintenance Plans\Backup Plan" -- which I can't find. The "Management\Maintenance Plans" area for my server is empty.

I imagine I could delete the existing plan and re-create it manually, but I was hoping to just modify what was already there, since all that's missing is deleting old files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the plan would have been on the server already.  Did you restore MSDB? this would be the only case when the backup job would be moved to a new server, as msdb is the store for sql server agent jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Just create new task (with Maintenance Cleanup task) to delete old backups/logs and set schedule appropriate time (e.g after your backup is finished)

Answer (score 0):

How did you import it? I have never had a database import (attach, backup restore) add a maintenance plan. Never. Now, that said - it could possibly try to do that once the db starts using a stored procedure.

Comment: I know. Weird. Imported using backup-restore mechanics. That's why I assumed it's a "default" thing.